# Applying function to loc call in pandas is causing changes to the underlying dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm using .apply in pandas.  I applied a function called `clean_alts(x)` (see below) to a dataframe series called 'alts', containing lists of strings (alternative forms of words) or 0 values (int) where there are no alternative forms to list.  The goal was to iterate through the word lists, where they exist, and for each string, split at the first '|' and take what comes before.

When I run `df.loc[:,'alts'].apply(lambda x: clean_alts(x)` to test the function, the function does this successfully.

However, if I then run `df['alts']`, I see that the underlying dataframe series has been altered as well, with the same changes.  My understanding has been that using apply without an assignment should never alter the underlying dataframe.

I'm concerned by this behavior, I don't want to move forward without understanding why an operation on a temporary copy of the df would affect the underlying df.

The same thing happens when using .map, and the same thing happens if I use df[df[...] to filter instead of using loc.

I tried mapping a simple lambda x: str(x) to the column and this did NOT affect the underlying dataframe.

So, is it something about the way I designed the function?

Here's the function I'm applying

```
def clean_alts(x):
    if type(x)==list:
        for i in range(len(x)):
            if '|' in x[i]:
                x[i] = x[i].split('|')[0]
    return x
```

Testing the function (the code that changed the underlying df):

```
df.loc[:,'alts'].apply(lambda x: clean_alts(x))
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for questions requesting debugging help. In any case "My understanding has been that using apply without an assignment should never alter the underlying dataframe." Well, but your *function modifies the `list`object inside the Series*: `x[i] = x[i].split('|')[0]`. So of course, the changes are reflected in the series, because it's still holding the same objects as before, and you've mutated them with `.apply` (not a good approach, generally)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to juanpa.arrivillaga for clarifying, I suspected the assignment in the function might be to blame but wanted to confirm that the behavior was expected.

Here is a simpler version of the function which is successful and does not affect the underlying df:

```
def clean_alts(x):
    if type(x)==list:
        return [i.split('|')[0] for i in x]
    else:
        return x
```